# Running a function in a 1 line for loop Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Is it possible to call a function in a for loop in one line?

Example:

```
print("Hello") for x in range(4)
```

Would print

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: It's probably worth asking *why* you want to do this.  The answer's below will work, but I don't know very many python coders who would write it all on one line like that...

Comment: You could have tried it yourself. The answer is No. http://ideone.com/wrv56O

Comment: ah, @BrunoToffolo, you've misinterpreted his question.  he's not asking whether that particular line of code works.  he's asking whether there is a line of code that can be written in python that would print the desired output, given something like that input.

Answer (score 3):

You have the ordering wrong, but yes it is possible. Simply write a `for` loop as per usual, however simply stay on the same line for your statement.

```
>>> for x in range(4): print("Hello")
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

I rarely (*if ever*) write `for` loops like this in one line however, as it tends to reduce your code's readability (*IMHO, others may disagree*) and doesn't really serve a purpose in cases like this. Writing generator expressions or list comprehensions on a single line is a different story.

Answer (score 3):

You could use join function also.

```
>>> print('\n'.join("Hello" for x in range(4)))
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
for x in range(4): print("Hello")
```

In Python 3, because `print` is a function, you could also use a list comprehension:

```
[print("Hello") for x in range(4)]
```

Comment: "you could also use a list comprehension" - but it would be an awful idea and no one should ever do it.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I'm asking is because my instructor pushes us to reach a low line count (a challenge to write shorter code).

Comment: In that case, I recommend looking elsewhere for terseness, as `if x: print(0)` is syntactically identical to `if x:\n    print(0)`. It's basically [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)), which is not related to code quality.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with those constructs is that they create a `generator` object.

This does not work:

```
>>> print("Hello") for x in range(4)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("Hello") for x in range(4)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't print what you wanted, either:

```
>>> (print("Hello") for x in range(4))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002497090>
```

This prints what you want, but also returns a `list` filled with `None` (not an issue outside of the interactive interpreter):

```
>>> [print("Hello") for x in range(4)]
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
[None, None, None, None]
```

This prints what you want, and suppresses the `None`-filled `list` by saving it to a variable:

```
>>> temp = [print("Hello") for x in range(4)]
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

What you might like is the following unrolled `generator` sent to `print`:

```
>>> print(*("Hello" for x in range(4)), sep='\n')
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

As a extension to Avinash's answer, you don't really need a for loop at all. Just *multiply* like so:

```
print(('Hello\n' * 4).rstrip('\n')) # strip the extra newline from printed stream
```